# Custom Login, Blazor Server and session timeouts using Claims

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Background:**
I am writing some Blazorserver applications.  My situation is that I need to authenticate from a local Active Directory, so I am using LDAP and I have that working.  I also have some applications that need a PIN style login and I have that working too.  I put it all into a library that I hope to use in all the projects I'm assigned to.

**Scenario**: The library uses a custom "LoginService" that includes all the logic for logging in and out and passes the ClaimsPrincipal to a RevalidatingServerAuthenticationHandler through SetAuthenticationState.  The periodic revalidation is also firing properly as expected.  I am using a claim to pass the expiration.

```
        protected override Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = authenticationState.User;
            if (cp.FindAll(c => c.Type == "ExpirationTimeStamp").SingleOrDefault() is Claim Expiry)
            {
                DateTime _expiryTimeStamp;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(Expiry.Value, out _expiryTimeStamp)) return Task.FromResult(false);
                return Task.FromResult(_expiryTimeStamp > DateTime.Now);
            };
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
```

**Question:** Is this bad practice in anyway?

I had tried to use and set cookies with httpcontextaccessor and SignInAsyncbut had some odd issues where the login page would not display the login box (which is a component in the library).

I have also used protectedbrowserstorage and that works fine but I'm not sure if there is a benefit.

Advice?